# Triple backticks code formatting doesn't show up in the suggested-edits queue on side-by-side mode

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, code-formatting, backtick

I just noticed that answers (I don't know about the questions), that used triple backticks codes in the body, don't show up in the suggested-edits review queue on side-by-side mode. Instead it shows an empty code block. See the pictures below:

| side-by-side | side-by-side Markdown |
| --- | --- |
| [image: suggested edits side-by-side] | [image: suggested edits side-by-side Markdown] |

[sample review item](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/376601)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is being rendered correctly. That code was previously being rendered as inline code because at the time it was posted we did not support triple backticks for a code block. Now that triple-backtick code blocks are supported, attempting to render it in the new Markdown engine produces an empty code block, because all of the text is on the first line of the backticks. Any text on the first line of backticks is interpreted as language hinting and is stripped from the output.

You can copy-paste that block of Markdown into any editor on the network, and it will continue producing an empty code block. It needs an additional line break after the first three backticks to be rendered correctly using that format.

Comment: no, but did you open the answer out of the edit review? it was showing up there normally. you mean if we tried to edit that answer, then in the editor window (now, after supporting triple backticks) those line will not appear but that answer because was old and that is why it was visible?

Comment: The live rendering of a post is cached. It was still being displayed as inline code because it had never been re-rendered. You can also see it rendered incorrectly from the revision history, which doesn't use cached versions of the post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/475756/revisions

Comment: @αғsнιη Markdown help for [info string](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#info-string). When editing [1 or more backticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcr9w.png) may appear the same, but doesn't produce the same result - think of one view as *raw* (or unrendered) and the other as rendered.